# How to autotag only the homepage of a website in ManicTime?

Tags: regex

I don't use social networks much. If I access them, usually because of a link related to my work appeared in Google. Visiting that link is still on work, but browsing the feed after reading that is not. So I would like to autotag only the homepage in a separated tag. For example, visiting `twitter.com/manictime` is work, but `twitter.com` is distraction.

I can use the `apply first autotag` feature, but I don't want to use this (btw, when does the feature work best? The tutorial page doesn't explain much). I guess in the custom field I can use regex, but using `twitter.com$` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the field at the bottom of the screen, type:

```
#"^twitter.com^"
```

Breaking down:
- `#"regex"` for every regex command in ManicTime
- `^xyz` means the string matches exactly `xyz